# What does `->` symbol represent in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I have been looking at some code and come across the symbol `->` being used like `obj->method(argument);` I have done a little bit of research and found it basically is the same as `[obj method:argument];` but I am unsure what `->` actually is or does.

So my question is, what does the `->` symbol mean in objective-c?

Comment: @JordiKroon I would tend to disagree that these are duplicates. This is asking what -> symbol means, whilst that question is asking the difference between "." and "->"

Comment: Same thing it represents in C, which you should learn before diving into Objective-C.

Comment: @HotLicks I developed loads of apps that are in the app store and I haven't had to learn what this is. The only reason I ask is because for the first time in 3 years I have seen it being used in some open source code. So I wouldn't say it needs to be learnt before diving into objective-c

Comment: @JoshCaswell Could possibly be the rude manner why someone has down voted?

Answer (score 6):

It means the same as the `struct` dereference operator does in C, which is used to access fields within the `struct` via a pointer:

```
struct mystruct
{
    int field;
};

struct mystruct *mystruct = ...;
printf("field=%d\n", mystruct->field);
```

In Objective-C it can also be used to access fields within Objective-C objects:

```
@interface MyObj : NSObject
{
@public
    int field;
}
@end

MyObj *myObj = [[MyObj alloc] init];
NSLog(@"field=%d", myObj->field);
```

Note that you can only access these fields externally if they are declared `@public`.

Comment: +1. Note that this second usage is not common (I've never personally used it in real shipping code), and that it's also actually the same exact thing as the first usage. Objective-C objects are implemented as structs internally, so a pointer to an object is actually a pointer to a struct.

Comment: Sort of as structs anyway;  they were straight structs up until the modern runtime.  Now there is a bit of magic to address the fragile base class problem (which allows ivars to be added to a base class without requiring subclasses to be recompiled).

Comment: @bbum and Andrew; one thing you can clarify to me is the OP claims to be able to call methods via `->`, but how is `self` passed to the method in this case; does the compiler just treat it like an Objective-C call?

Comment: Yeah -- no :) -- he can't call methods through that syntax.

Comment: Can't call *Objective-C* methods.  Can call C++ methods inside Objective-C++ modules.

Comment: I guess you can only do this using `methodForSelector` to get the method pointer and passing `self` and `_cmd` through explicitly? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtHowMessagingWorks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH104-TPXREF163

Answer (score 5):

> I have been looking at some code and come across the symbol -> being
>   used like obj->method(argument); I have done a little bit of research
>   and found it basically is the same as [obj method:argument]; but I am
>   unsure what -> actually is or does.
>
> So my question is, what does the -> symbol mean in objective-c?

Exactly the same thing it means in C;  it is for accessing an item in a C structure.   Way back in the days of yore, Objective-C was implemented purely as a C preprocessor extension + a runtime.    Classes were nothing more than concatenated C structures and the preprocessor turned each ivar access into `self->ivar`.

I.e. `ivar` and `self->ivar` do the same thing (in a method of class).

Now, you *can* use `->` to poke at some other object's (@public) ivars.   But don't.  That breaks encapsulation exactly because Objective-C's line of encapsulation is drawn at the method interface.   Always use the setters/getters such that behavior can be either observed or overridden.

Finally, no, there is nothing like `obj->method(argument)` anymore.  There was, once, in a failed experiment called *Modern Syntax*, but it was abandoned because it was a pointless waste of time.  You can't use `->` to invoke methods.

Comment: "You can't use -> to invoke methods."  What about in Objective-C++?

Comment: You can use it to invoke C++ methods, but not Objective-C methods.

Comment: +1 this is very informative thank you.